# Deploy de aplicação python em cluster kubernetes

Tags: python

Preciso fazer o deploy de uma aplicação python em um cluster `kubernetes`. Essa aplicação está utilizando o `venv` e eu não sei se é correto gerar uma imagem de container com o diretório do venv. Qual a maneira aconselhada para se criar uma imagem a partir de uma aplicação python que utiliza o venv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eu utilizo o docker, mas pode ser que seja de ajuda. Então eu so uso o virtualenv em desenvolvimento. Quando dou o deploy no meu dockerfile eu digo qual a imagem que eu uso no caso python 3.6 ai eu rodo tambem o pip install -r requiments.txt, sendo assim minha imagem vai conter os arquivos que preciso. Algo mais ou menos como isso:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && pip3 install pipenv

ADD ./src /app

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score -5):

Nesse caso você precisa dockerizar a sua aplicação, publicar em algum registry e via manifesto ou helm chart realizar o deploy no Kubernetes.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).